# Complicated vector multiplication without iterating through the vector

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to calculate a loss value in a variation of multiclass classification.

I have my `y` tensor (the values correspond to the classes):

```
y = torch.tensor([ 1,  0,  2])
```

My `y_pred` is a `3x3` matrix of probability distributions:

```
y_pred = torch.tensor([[0.4937, 0.2657, 0.2986],
        [0.2553, 0.3845, 0.4384],
        [0.2510, 0.3498, 0.2630]])
```

The complication is that I also have a distance matrix (each class has some distance to other classes):

```
d_mtx = torch.tensor([[0, 0.7256, 0.7433],
        [0.6281, 0, 0.1171],
        [0.7580, 0.2513, 0]])
```

The loss that I'm trying to calculate is:

```
loss = 0
for class_value in range(len(y)):
    dis = torch.dot(d_mtx[y[class_value]], y_pred[class_value])
    loss += dis
```

Is there a way to calculate it efficiently without the iteration?

**Update 1:**
Tried @Yahia Zakaria approach and it works if my `y_pred` has the same size as my `d_mtx`, but otherwise I get an error:

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (3) must match the size of tensor b (4) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

For example:

```
y = torch.tensor([ 1,  0,  2, 1])
y_pred = torch.tensor([[0.4937, 0.2657, 0.2986],
        [0.2553, 0.3845, 0.4384],
        [0.2510, 0.3498, 0.2630],
        [0.2510, 0.3498, 0.2630]])

d_mtx = torch.tensor([[0, 0.7256, 0.7433],
        [0.6281, 0, 0.1171],
        [0.7580, 0.2513, 0]])
```

Comment: There is one thing here that doesn't seem right. When you write `y_pred[class_value]`, both the first and the last value in `y` will refer to row 1 in `y_pred` so the last row will be ignored. Is that intended?

Comment: There is no value in `y` that is 3 so the last row in `y_pred` will never be used in the calculation.

Comment: Yea I see your point now, apologies I didn't realized I didn't write it correctly, I'm updating my question. Sorry again, does it makes more sense now?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like that:

```
loss = (d_mtx[y] * y_pred).sum()
```

This solution assumes the `y` is of type `torch.int64` which is valid for the example you have shown.

Comment: Nice! I like that "trick" with `distance[y]`. Thanks!

Comment: I just realized that this almost works. Please see my update!

Comment: Updated the solution to address the question update.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks again.